# Can I send message to clients who are present in N groups on SignalR Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Can I send message to clients who are present in N groups on SignalR Core?

I need to send message to clients that are present in N groups, something like this

| Group Name | Clients |
| --- | --- |
| groupA | 01, 02, **03**, **04**, 05 |
| groupB | **03**, **04**, 05, 22, 25 |
| groupC | **03**, **04**, 40, 50, 60 |

I need to send a message to clients  03, 04 that are present in all groups (A, B and C).

I didn't find this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-7.0#groups-in-signalr) , does anyone know if it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build-in feature for this requirement. You need to write your own code to maintain the connectionId and group information for establishing a connection.

**Like below:**

```
public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> My_Groups = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

**Description**

For ConnectedUsers, one userid may have multiple signalr connectionIds.

For My_Groups, one user could in  multiple groups.

**Since no build-in feature, the solution like below**

Use foreach to traverse the connectionId of the connected users in the groups, and then pick out the connected users that each group has.

Comment: I see, that's how I was thinking, but I thought it might have build-in SignalR feature :/
Thanks for the answer